# Open new folder window in Finder El Capitan - instead of same window

Tags: finder, macos, folders

I have different Finder window sizes for almost each folder and just updated to El Capitan.

Now sometimes it opens in the same folder and sometimes it even uses the last open folder like when I chose "Applications" from the menu. 
I can use cmd-double click and this usually helps. But sometimes I forget and thus half of the day I spend resizing my windows to the old size. 
Is there a Terminal code I can use to always use a new window when opening a folder?

---

even a call with apple did not bring a new idea. So I will close this question. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 1):

Without installing additional software you get the wanted Finder behavior by hiding the toolbar and the sidebar.

[image]

Comment: great idea, I will check this, thanks a lot
re: Without installing additional software
what software would that be? sth like onyx? or a terminal code?

Comment: @Tina No, a window manager like Divvy. This doesn't really solve the "new" window problem though.

Comment: after checking every possibility I could find, I gave up. There is only the solution  mentioned above, hiding the menus or pressing cmd when double clicking. btw: you do not need this with folders on the desktop, they always open in a new window. that seems self explanatory, but it is not, because: when using the menu on top of the display, when I click applications it opens in the folder opened last not in a new one. .